# Polychoric Correlations to Fisher's Z Transformation

Tags: r, meta-analysis, metafor, fisher-transform, polychoric

I'm interested in conducting a meta-analysis of polychoric correlation coefficients using  `metafor` package in R.

When performing a meta-analysis with Pearson correlations, I know that I would typically transform the raw correlations into Fisher's Z scores (and later re-transform the final results).

However, I'm uncertain whether the same transformation process can be applied to polychoric correlations.

Comment: I think this as come up in the R list on meta-analysis but I cannot find it there. I think the answer was negative but we should wait for someone else to confirm that. You could try asking on that list of course but please link back here so it does not get answered twice.